# Partitioning with Primary Key

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-OVERVIEW notes the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE measurement (
    city_id         int not null,
    logdate         date not null,
    peaktemp        int,
    unitsales       int
) PARTITION BY RANGE (logdate);
```

If I try to create a primary key on `city_id`, it fails:

```
postgres=#CREATE TABLE measurement (
        city_id         int not null,
        logdate         date not null,
        peaktemp        int,
        unitsales       int,
        PRIMARY KEY (city_id)
    ) PARTITION BY RANGE (logdate);
ERROR:  unique constraint on partitioned table must include all partitioning columns
DETAIL:  PRIMARY KEY constraint on table "measurement" lacks column "logdate" which is part of the partition key.
```

If I add `logdate` to the PK, it works:

```
postgres=#CREATE TABLE measurement (
        city_id         int not null,
        logdate         date not null,
        peaktemp        int,
        unitsales       int,
        PRIMARY KEY (city_id, logdate)
    ) PARTITION BY RANGE (logdate);
CREATE TABLE
```

However, let's say that's meaningless to my schema. I want to enforce a single `city_id` across all data.

What are my options?

Comment: If `city_id` is unique in this table, there can't be more than one measurement for each city, therefore partitioning by date is meaningless. I suppose you need to think a little bit more about your data model, or show your _actual_ model in the question.

Comment: You have to decide which is more important, partitioning by date, or having a primary key  which doesn't include date.

Answer (score 0):

Something will have to give. The alternatives are:

1. You live without a primary key on the partitioned table and instead define primary key constraints on all partitions of the table. That guarantees uniqueness within a single partition. Unless you need foreign keys that point to the partitioned table, that is the way to go, and foreign keys pointing to the partitioned table are questionable anyway, as they will prevent you from detaching partitions.
2. Add the partitioning key to the primary key.

No matter how you do it, you will not be able to guarantee the uniqueness of `city_id`. Consider it a price to pay for the benefits you get from partitioning.